# How do I animate an Image ScaleTransform from C# in a WPF program?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to animate this ScaleTransform

```
       <Image x:Name="photoB" Height="290"  Width="420" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
             <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="40" ScaleX="40"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
       </Image>
```

The problem is I can't find a TargetProperty that makes WPF happy!

I've tried things like

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(kenBurnsAnimationA, new PropertyPath("(Image.RenderTransform)[0].ScaleTransform.ScaleX"));
```

and

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(kenBurnsAnimationA, new PropertyPath("ScaleTransform.ScaleX"));
```

and

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(kenBurnsAnimationA, new PropertyPath("(Image.RenderTransform.TransformGroup.ScaleTransform.ScaleX"));
```

but nothing seems to work.

What's the secret for C# "CodeBehind" of XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to add an empty Image.RenderTransform TransformGroup to my XAML

```
       <Image x:Name="photoA" Height="290"  Width="420" Stretch="Uniform" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform />
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
```

You can't animate these if they don't exist! I suppose I could have added the transfer group from C# as well.

Thanks @Anton Tykhyy for pointing me to the corrrect path.

Comment: You certainly can't animate them if they don't exist. The XAML in your question showed them as existing so I assumed they exist :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)`.

Comment: Nope! That gives me
    Additional information: '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(Image.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)'.

Comment: Ok! I got it! The problem was that I needed to have a Transform group (empty) in the XAML.